# VBScript moved and new created file with same date-time

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm using the following code to rotate log files. If the Log.txt file is different than the current date-time (based on file property .DateCreated), the file is moved using the .DateCreated value to rename it and then a new Log.txt file is created but the new file date created value is the same as the moved (archived) file.

If the script is run again a few seconds later it fails to move the Log.txt file as an archived version already exist.

```
Option Explicit

 Dim objFS: Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Dim strLogPath: strLogPath = "C:\Logs"
 Dim strLogFQFN: strLogFQFN = objFS.BuildPath(strLogPath, "Log.txt")
 
  If objFS.FileExists(strLogFQFN) <> True Then
   WScript.Quit
  End If

  'As file exists, validate if archive is needed
  Dim objFile: Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strLogFQFN)

  Dim dtmLog: dtmLog = objFile.DateCreated'DateValue(objFile.DateCreated)
  Dim dtmNow: dtmNow = Now 'Date
  Set objFile = Nothing
  WScript.Echo dtmLog
  WScript.Echo dtmNow
  If (dtmLog <> dtmNow) Then
   Dim tsDate: tsDate = DatePart("yyyy", dtmLog) & "-" & Right("0" & DatePart("m", dtmLog), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & DatePart("d", dtmLog), 2)
   Dim tsTime : tsTime = Right("0" & Hour(dtmLog), 2) & Right("0" & Minute(dtmLog), 2) & Right("0" & Second(dtmLog), 2)
   Call objFS.MoveFile(strLogFQFN, objFS.BuildPath(strLogPath, tsDate & "T" & tsTime & ".txt"))
   Call objFS.CreateTextFile(strLogFQFN, False)
  End If
```

[1st run - Original file Log.txt moved to 2022-03-11T014931.txt and new Log.txt created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtFxB.png)

[1st and 2nd run date-time values and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23jbU.png)

Thanks

Comment: Might have something to do with the permissions in C drive, see if it happens if the folder is in another drive, like `D:\Logs`

Comment: You are right. Directly on C or any other subfolder (even user's Documents) is not working, but moving the Log.txt to D works as expected. Could you elaborate more about the _permissions in C_?

Comment: Also, note that **Date created** is affected by [file tunneling](https://web.archive.org/web/20140528165711/https://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=172190). That is, if you create a new file within a short time of deleting a file of the same name, the new file will retain the original file's Date created. You may be better off using **Date modified**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on LesFerch comment I have tested adding a delay of 16 seconds to overcome the default Tunneling cache time and that resolved the issue using the C drive.

```
Call objFS.MoveFile(strLogFQFN, objFS.BuildPath(strLogPath, tsDate & "T" & tsTime & ".txt"))
WScript.Sleep 16000
Call objFS.CreateTextFile(strLogFQFN, False)
```